# spark structured streaming with large window size: memory consumption

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We plan to implement a Spark Structured Streaming application which will consume a continuous flow of data: evolution of a metric value over time.
This streaming application will work with a window size of 7 days (and a sliding window) in order to frequently calculate the average of the metric value over the last 7 days.

1-  Will Spark retain all those  7 days of data (impacting a lot the memory consumed), OR Spark continuously calculates and updates the average requested (and then get rid of handled data) and so does not impact so much memory consumed (not retaining 7 days of data) ?

2-  In case answer to first question is that those 7 days of data are retained, does the usage of watermark prevent this retention ?
Let’s say that we have a watermark of 1 hour; will only 1 hour of data be retained in Spark, OR 7 days are still retained in spark memory and watermark is here just for ignoring new data coming in with a datatimestamp older than 1 hour ?

Answer (score 1):

Window Size 7 is definitely a significant one, but it also depends on the streaming data volume/records coming in. The trick lies in how to use the **Window duration, update interval, output mode and if necessary the watermark** (if the business rule is not impacted)

1-  If the streaming is configured to be of tumbling window size (ie the window duration is same as the update duration), with complete mode, you may end up full data being kept in memory for 7 days. However, if you configure the window duration to be 7 days with an update of every x minutes, aggregates will be calculated every x minutes and only the result data will be kept in memory. Hence look at the window API parameters and configure the way to get the results.

2- Watermark brings a different behaviour and it ignores the records before the watermark duration and update the result tables after every micro batch crosses the water mark time. If your business rule is ok to include watermark calculation, it is fine to use it too.

It is good to go through the API in detail, output modes and watermark usage at [enter link description here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time)
This would help to choose the right combination.